# Google Backup and Sync is adding some files to my drive

Tags: google-drive

I uploaded my entire catalog of photos (about 15k) to Google Photos using the Backup and Sync tool. Some images are JPG and most of them are supported RAW files (CR2 or ARW). I noticed yesterday that my Google Drive filled up.

I emptied my trash and noticed that some files, that were only to be synced with Google Photos, were added within my drive. They were added under Computers > My Macbook Pro > all of my files. I deleted that entire directory and re-synced my Google Photos. That drive was added back under "Computers". After the process completed, I looked at my quota and noticed that some photos were added to my Google Drive and were taking up space while others within the same directory were not taking up any space.

I'd like to keep my Google Photos outside of my Google Drive. Is there a step I missed or something else I can do? Or, is this a bug?

I've added screenshots about more specific details about my issue:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to keep my Google Photos outside of my Google Drive. Is there a step I missed or something else I can do? Or, is this a bug?

No bug. Feature. Backup and Sync moves everything to your drive, and the Photos checkbox just means your images are *also* added to your Photos library. Images that normally wouldn't take up space in the Photos app also do not count towards your drive quota so don't worry about paying double for space. To be clear: B&S can't upload directly to Photos without putting files on Drive.

The other problem you seem to be having is that you don't expect your quota to be used, so I'm assuming you have the "High Quality" setting in B&S preferences. But remember that images must meet certain criteria for waving the storage? It could be that your specific RAW is not supported (see [here](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313#raw)).

Comment: ah cool. The old Google Photos app allowed the user to upload straight to Google Photos. That was nice! All of my images should be within the criteria for free "High Quality" storage.

Comment: @Dan Maybe you can upload one of the quota-consuming files directly to Photos and see if it still takes space.